# Creating a generic payload class

Tags: c++

my task is to place specified bits in an array of 8 bytes (not all 64 bits).

This can be done by using a struct:

```
struct Date {
   unsigned int nWeekDay  :  3;
   unsigned int nMonthDay :  6;
   unsigned int reserved1 : 10;
   unsigned int nMonth    :  5;
   unsigned int nYear     :  8;
};
```

I would like to write a generic class that gets value, start bits and length and place the the value a the correct position.

Could someone point me to an implementation of such a class\function?

Comment: Do you mean something like `array[0] = someDate.nWeekday;`? What have you tried? What problems do you have with your code?

Comment: What's wrong with something like `mem=(mem&((1<<length)-1)<<start)|(value<<start);`?

Comment: You can also access bits without using a structure.  Using a common or generic class may be more complicated than accessing the bits directly.